# C++ overloading '+' operator to get sum of data from 2 different linked lists

Tags: c++

I am asked to overload operator '+' into the list class. I want the sum of all cgpa points of students from 2 different linked lists but don't know how to do it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;



class StudentGroup
{
public:
 struct Node
 {
  char* name;
  double cgpa;
  Node* next;
 };
 Node* head = 0;
 
public:
 StudentGroup()
 {
  head = nullptr;
 }
 StudentGroup(const StudentGroup &list);
 ~StudentGroup();
 bool insert(char* name, double cgpa);
 bool removeNode(char* name);
 void print();
 double& cumulativeGPA(char* name);
};
```

above code is what I've done for class definition.

```
bool StudentGroup::insert(char* name, double cgpa)
{
 bool Insert = false;
 Node* temp;
 Node* newnode = new Node();
 newnode->name = new char[strlen(name)+1];
 strcpy(newnode->name,name);
 newnode->cgpa = cgpa;
 newnode->next = 0;
 if (head == 0)
 {
  head = temp = newnode;
 }
 else
 {
  temp->next = newnode;
  temp = newnode;
 }
 Insert = true;
 return Insert;
}
```

and here is the code I wrote to create lists and add objects to them.

```
    int main()
{
 StudentGroup list1, list3, list4;

    list3.insert("Michael Faraday", 4.2);
    list3.insert("Marie Curie", 3.8);
    list4.insert("Albert Einstein", 4.2);
    list4.insert("Alan Turing", 3.8);
 
 //Copy constructor
    StudentGroup list2=list1;
 list1.~StudentGroup();
 list2.print();
 list1.print();

    //Operator overloading
 list3.print();
 list4.print();
 list3 = list4;
}
```

and above is the main function. What I need is something like:

```
  list3+list4//code
  16//output
```

How to do that? Sorry if my question doesn't fit the usual format, complete beginner here and due to limited time I had to ask.

Comment: `list1.~StudentGroup();` ... I don't think you are taking the advanced course at this point so you may want to remove that. You are not supposed to call destructors like ordinary functions. They are either called automatically (for automatic variables) or you should `delete` instances (that have been dynamically allocated)

Comment: Strong recommendation: Separate the linked list logic from the data contained by the linked list and the user of the linked list. With the responsibilities separated you have three small pieces of code you can test and validate separately, and smaller code generally has fewer bugs you need to fix. Lump them all together and you have to test them together and untangle whatever bugs they have in order to fix them.

Comment: `StudentGroup` has a destructor and a copy constructor, but no assignment operator to finish off the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). This means the program will be completely <expletive deleted>ed when it hits `list3 = list4;`

Comment: `char* name;` -- Why not `std::string name;`?  Then you won't need this: `newnode->name = new char[strlen(name)+1];`

Comment: Well, @Paul , according to Jean-Jacques Rousseau, "Man is born to suffer; pain is the means of his preservation."

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie well I don't get it either, my professor said using char* was a requirement, and using string was forbidden for the task at hand. So yeah ask my professor. lol

Comment: @EgemenInanc `std::string` has been standard C++ for 24 years now.  Why in the world are so-called "professors" teaching C++ in this fashion in this day and age?  It's requirements like these is the reason why new programmers drop C++ and instead learn Python or some other language.  Professors and curriculums with these nutty requirements, IMO, are detrimental in the growth of having more programmers use C++.

Comment: Tactical note: "You can't use `string`" is often secret teacher code for "Write your own `string`." Adding string management to all of the other responsibilities of a class once again means you wind up having to test multiple things at a time. If you bundle the string management up into its own class, you can validate it on its own and then just use it once you know it works correctly. In general you want mall classes you can use as building blocks to make higher-level constructs easily.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is a questionable style. Save yourself a lot of grief down the road and `std::cout << ...`. instead...

Comment: As @user4581301 suggests, using `operator+` to add the lists suggests something other than what you want. Ideally, the `StudentGroup` class would have a `sum_cgpa()` member and you would add the two sums instead.   But just be aware that a sum of GPAs is statistically meaningless.

Comment: A *proper* modern C++ solution would be to ditch the `Node` struct altogether and use `std::(forward_)list` instead. And then you can use `std::accumulate()` or `std::reduce()` to calculate the sum of the nodes in a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as looping through both lists/groups and adding up their cpga:

```cpp
// put inside class declaration
double operator+(const StudentGroup& student2);

// function definition
double StudentGroup::operator+(const StudentGroup& student2)
{
    double ret = 0.0;
    Node* pStudent;

    for (pStudent = this->head; pStudent; pStudent = pStudent->next)
        ret += pStudent->cgpa;

    for (pStudent = student2.head; pStudent; pStudent = pStudent->next)
        ret += pStudent->cgpa;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Side note: I wouldn't use a + operator for this task because this isn't the behaviour I'd expect from a + operator. Typically `list1 +list2` would result in a `list3` that contained copies of all of the items in `list1` and `list2`, the concatenation of two lists. I would not expect a summation of the items in two lists. Good clean solution, though.